# Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit issue while decryption java

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, base64, rsa

I am working on a spring boot application where I am decoding a String using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding and private key but getting the following error:
`Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit`

Here are my Decryption cipher and decrypt method:

```
    @Bean
    public PrivateKey getBtoBPrivateKey() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String privateK = fetchStringFileFromS3(certificateBucket,iciciBtobPrivateKeyFile);
        String privateKeyPEM = privateK
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        log.info(privateKeyPEM);
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        return  keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("btob_decryption_cipher")
    public Cipher getBtoBDecryptCipher() throws Exception {
        Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getBtoBPrivateKey());
        return decryptionCipher;
    }
```

Now Below is how I am decrypting my string using the private key and getting the error:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("btob_decryption_cipher")
private Cipher btobDecryptionCipher;


public synchronized byte[] btobDecryptRSA(String encryptedData){
        try {
            encryptedData = encryptedData.replace(" ","");
            return btobDecryptionCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder()
                    .decode(encryptedData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error("decryptRSA process failed",e);
            throw new IciciBankPaymentException("decryptRSA process failed");
        }
    }
```

The same private key is working and successfully decrypting in online decrypter.

My KEY:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Your code is doing something with your `privateKeyPEM` , if possible share the key as well so that it can be reproduced.

Comment: @Rishal added my key

Comment: also I think the issue is after I convert my encrypted string to byte array,can you check there once?

Comment: is your key has only one equals at last ? is the key correct?

Comment: yes key is correct,I tried with online RSA decrypter

Comment: Since you use the Base64 decoder for the ciphertext, the data seems to be Base64 encoded. Are they? Then why the line `encryptedData = encryptedData.replace(" ","")`? There are no spaces in a Base64 encoded string! Where exactly does the error occur? Post the stack trace please.

Comment: Yes they are base64 encoded,I was sending them in request param thats why space was there

Comment: I am sending them in requestBody now and now no space issue is there

Comment: When sending base64 in request parameters, you must either url-encode it, or ensure you're using base64url, not normal base64, because for example the `+` will be decoded to a space. Alternatively, a bit dirty and hacky, use `encryptedData.replace(" ","+")` instead.

Comment: sending data in request is figured now,still stuck on the decryption part